# "Category(#2203433720) expected, got String(#2155957040)" Collection_select returning string instead of integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models "Events" and "Categories". Event model has integer type "category" that belongs_to "Category". Category model has key:value that stores these categories such as 1: Medical 2: Health 3: Food, etc.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, foreign_key: "category"
end
```

My schema is:

```
create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "events", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.integer  "category"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I am using simple forms and maybe this is where I am going wrong but I am returning the right value but just as a string. For example, if I selected medical from the drop down it would be return the correct "1" but just as a string and not the required integer.

/views/events

```
<%= f.input :category, as: :select, collection: Category.all, include_blank: "Select a category..." %>
```

My drop down is displaying properly and returning the correct value but as a string and not an integer. Is there a best way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have `f.input :category_id`, as that is what is being submitted, the ID of the category you select, not the category itself.

Comment: This is in my "Events" view. I don't have an attribute :category_id. :category should do the same thing as I have it set up, correct?

Comment: This is weird because I went into my schema and changed Event.category => Event.category_id and changed it in the MVC and it seemed to strangely work. Is there some sort of Rails naming convention I wasn't following?

Comment: Yes, the default foreign key for a belongs_to association is `(association name)_id` - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association